# How to use SocketIOClient in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, websocket, socket.io

I want to send json data from unity client to asp.net server. I've build the application on my mobile phone(android) so that I need the websocket supported on android platform. I don't know what socketIO  .Net server will use but it probably use SignalR. Is it possible that i use 'SocketIO' in unity? Then, could you guys check my code please?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using SocketIOClient;


public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    string socketUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:3000";
    Debug.Log("socket url: " + socketUrl);

            //Client client = new Client (socketUrl);
            //client.Send ("hello world!");

    Client client = new Client(socketUrl);

    client.Opened += SocketOpened;
    //client.Message += SocketMessage;
    //client.SocketConnectionClosed += SocketConnectionClosed;
    //client.Error +=SocketError;
    //string message = "Unity : message";
    string message = "Unity - message";
    client.Send(message);
    client.Connect();   
    }

private void SocketOpened(object sender, MessageEventArgs e) {
    //invoke when socket opened
    Debug.Log ("Hello");
}
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I decided the problem to use Websocket-Sharp. I tested with asp.net server as well to send json data. It worked well. 
Here is my code below.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using WebSocketSharp;
using System.IO;

public class socket : MonoBehaviour {


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    //Debug.Log ("start");
    test ();
    //Debug.Log ("end");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

private void test()
{
    // Create empty JSONOBJECT
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject (JSONObject.Type.OBJECT);
    // Add Field (ref. protocol.docx)
    j.AddField ("cType", "auto");
    j.AddField ("indexOrder", "1");
    j.AddField ("oderCount", "1");
    j.AddField ("arSpeed", "1000");
    j.AddField ("mSpeed", "1000 ");
    j.AddField ("arM1", "180");
    j.AddField ("arM2", "180");
    j.AddField ("arM3", "180");
    j.AddField ("arM4", "180");
    j.AddField ("arM5", "180");
    j.AddField ("arM6", "180");
    j.AddField ("emer", "0");
    j.AddField ("direcM1", "0");
    j.AddField ("speedM1", "0");
    j.AddField ("direcM2", "0");
    j.AddField ("speedM2", "0");
    //j.AddField ("rollDirecM1", "0");
    //j.AddField ("rollSpeedM1", "0");
    //j.AddField ("rollDirecM2", "0");
    //j.AddField ("rollSpeedM2", "0");

    string encodedString = j.Print ();
    Debug.Log (encodedString);

    WebSocket ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.172.0.1:3000");
    ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
        Debug.Log("Laputa says: " + e.Data);
    ws.Connect();
    ws.Send (encodedString);
    //ws.Send("Unity!!");
}
}
```

Comment: Which version of Unity you use? Unity Pro or Free?

Comment: @BarışÇırıka I'm using Unity Pro version. I thought that the Unity supports websocket library but i couldn't find anything related Websocket when i tpying "using". so i'm struggling to use 'websocket-sharp' but it doesn't have enough sample though.... I'm not really professional about server or client. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You can use [this](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21721)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about sockets in Unity, I'm just trying to figure it out myself.  However, are you sure you want to be creating your client in the `Update()` function?  It looks to me like Unity will be trying to create a whole new client every single frame.  I imagine this could be the cause of many different problems.

Maybe the reason the SocketIOClient code fails and the WebSocket code works is because you have the WebSocket code called from the `Start()` function instead of the `Update()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can use signalR with SocketIOClient.

I agree with Harrison. You should place the socket creation in `start()` function and using `update()` to handle sockets events.